# How does a Pull Request append an empty commit?

Tags: git, merge, azure-devops, pull-request

When we create a Pull Request, Visual Studio Team Services adds an empty commit to the source branch with the message:

> Merge PR XY from src-branch into target-branch.

I inspected the git commands that VSTS issues but couldn't find any related command.

Does anybody know how it's done?

**PS:** As an example, in the picture below, commit *a8581061* is done by VSTS whereas commit *5adb8333* was in bramch *features/add-serilog*.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "VSTS adds an empty commit to the source branch"? Can you add related screen shots?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Updated

Comment: The screen shot can not show the `develop` branch entirely, so the branch sturcture can not be check clearly. Can you show the whole develop branch or what's the output `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all` in your local repo (local repo should be sync with remote)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're not doing anything out of the ordinary; just accepting a pull request is going to create that commit.

BTW, the notion that a merge commit is "empty" is not correct. The merge commit contains all the changes from the branch that is merged(`features/add-serilog` in this context) and is made on top of the branch that is merged into(`develop`).

You can recreate this behavior by using the `git merge` command; just go onto `develop` and do `git merge features/add-serilog`. You'll get a prompt to edit the commit message defaulting to something like `Merge branch 'features/add-serilog' into 'develop'`. Saving changes will create your commit. When you push that commit, the pull request will get closed automatically(note that this only works if the pull request is initially open and you have permission to push to `develop` branch).

Comment: In a way, yes. `git pull` calls `git merge` internally. It's just a fetch followed by a merge.